# calculate IP header len

Tags: c, sockets, ip

I am trying to frame the ICMP packet and send it through raw socket.  Looking at the examples, I see that the IP packet length is calculated as :

iphdr.ip_hl = sizeof(struct ip) >> 2

Can you please explain why we need to right shift struct ip by 2 times instead of assigning a constan value ?

Comment: That *is* a constant value.  What are you asking?

Comment: You have a point there. Could you show these examples? Someone wants just 4 times the size of struct ip, which I can't understand without seeing the context.

Comment: @pbhd, 1/4 of the size, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'ip_hl' field of an IP (or ICMP) packet is defined as the length of the IP header, in 32-bit words.

sizeof(struct ip) yields the length of the IP header, in 8-bit bytes.  Right shifting this value twice provides the length in 32-bit words, as expected in the ip_hl field.

A good reason not to use a constant for this, is to eliminate magic numbers in source code. (The compiler will generate a constant value anyway for 'sizeof(struct ip) >> 2').

Answer (score 1):

Because 4-bit header length field is the number of ***32-bit words in the header, including options***, so it might be longer then 20 bytes (field value 5), so it's not supposed to be a constant value. Your examples just assume no options scenario.